# Having issue in shared hosting "Resource Limit Is Reached"

Tags: resources, web-hosting

I have hosted my site to cpanel when i am loading i am getting the resource limit issue

Here i have attached this error image 
[image]

Comment: probably your script uses too much CPU or RAM or something. The hosting provider might be able to tell you exactly what limit it exceeded, or perhaps there's a report available in the cPanel. Meanwhile you should fix your code so it's not so much of a resource hog

Answer (score 1):

It could be potential problem with either your CPU/Memory usage or database connection.

1. Check `max.concurrent.connection` value in your MYSQL configuration. That describes how many concurrent connections can be made simultaneously to the database. If you are number of connections beyond the numbers defined in the property, that will cause the problem.
2. Another issue can be if you are running out of CPU or RAM on your server. You need to free up some resources.